# How to mock async call in React functional component using jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, async-await, jestjs

I am testing a functional component that has a submit button that makes an async call to an api. The async call is located within a custom hook. As per standard testing practices, I have mocked the hook, so that my mock will be called instead of the actual async api:

```
someComponent.test.js

jest.mock("../../../CustomHooks/user", () => ({
  useUser: () => ({
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    forgotPassword: <SOMETHING HERE>

  })
}));
```

I know that my `forgotPassword` function is called because when I change it to `forgotPassword: ""`, I get an error in my test stating that forgotPassword is not a function.

A very simple representation of the function that is called when my submit button is clicked is this:

```
someComponent.js

import { useUser } from "../../../CustomHooks/user"

const SomeComponent = () => {

  ....state and other things etc....

  const { error, loading, forgotPassword } = useUser()

  const submit = async () => {
      await forgotPassword(emailValue);
      setState(prevState => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          content: "code"
        };
      });
  }

}
```

NOTE: My call to the async function `await forgotPassword...` is wrapped in a try/catch block in my code, but I have left this out for clarity.

In production, when the submit button is pressed, the async call occurs, and then the state should be switched, thus rendering some other components. My test looks to see if these components have been rendered (I am using react testing library for this).

The problem that I am having is that no matter what I place in the  placeholder of the first code block, my test will always fail as the setState block is never reached. If I remove the `await` statement, then the setState block is hit and the component that I want to appear is there as the state has changed. However, obviously this will not work as intended outside of the test as the actual call is asynchronous. Here are some of the approaches that I have tried that do not work:

```
DOESN'T WORK

forgotPassword: () => {
      return Promise.resolve({ data: {} });
    }
```

```
DOESN'T WORK

forgotPassword: jest.fn(() => {
      return Promise.resolve();
    })
```

```
DOESN'T WORK

forgotPassword: jest.fn(email => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (email) {
          resolve(email);
        } else {
          reject("Error");
        }
      });
    }),
```

As I have said already, if I remove the `await` statement, then the state changes and the component appears, and hence the test passes. However, for obvious reasons, this is not what I want.

***Extra Info***

Here is a simplified version of my test:

```
it("changes state/content from email to code when submit clicked", () => {
  const { getByTestId, getByText, debug } = render(<RENDER THE COMPONENT>);

  const submitButton = getByTestId("fpwSubmitButton");
  expect(submitButton).toBeInTheDocument();

  const emailInput = getByTestId("fpwEmailInput");

  fireEvent.change(emailInput, {
    target: { value: "testemail@testemail.com" }
  });

  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  debug();

  THE STATEMENTS BELOW ARE WHERE IT FAILS AS THE STATE DOESN'T CHANGE WHEN AWAIT IS PRESENT

  const codeInput = getByTestId("CodeInput");
  expect(codeInput).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To anyone who encounters this same problem, I found three ways that this can be solved (the preferred method is Option 3). All methods use a simple mock function that replaces the `<SOMETHING HERE>` of the first code block in my question. This can be replaced with `() => {}`:

```
jest.mock("../../../CustomHooks/user", () => ({
  useUser: () => ({
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    forgotPassword: () => {}
  })
}));
```

***Option 1***

The first approach is to wrap your test code that relies on an async function in a `setTimeout` with a `done` callback:

```
it("changes state/content from email to code when submit clicked", done => {
  const { getByTestId, debug } = render(<RENDER THE COMPONENT>);

  const submitButton = getByTestId("fpwSubmitButton");
  expect(submitButton).toBeInTheDocument();

  const emailInput = getByTestId("fpwEmailInput");

  fireEvent.change(emailInput, {
    target: { value: "testemail@testemail.com" }
  });

  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  setTimeout(() => {
    const codeInput = getByTestId("CodeInput");
    expect(codeInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    done();
  });

  debug();
});
```

Notice on the top line the `done` call back, as well as the test code wrapped in `setTimeout` at the bottom, and then invoking the callback within the setTimeout to tell jest that the test is done. If you don't call the `done` callback, the test will fail as it will timeout.

***Option 2***

The second approach is to use a function called `flushPromises()`:

```
function flushPromises() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
}

it("changes state/content from email to code when submit clicked", async () => {
  const { getByTestId, debug } = render(<RENDER THE COMPONENT>);

  const submitButton = getByTestId("fpwSubmitButton");
  expect(submitButton).toBeInTheDocument();

  const emailInput = getByTestId("fpwEmailInput");

  fireEvent.change(emailInput, {
    target: { value: "testemail@testemail.com" }
  });

  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  await flushPromises();

  const codeInput = getByTestId("CodeInput");
  expect(codeInput).toBeInTheDocument();

  debug();
});
```

Notice the `flushPromises()` function at the top, and then the call site towards the bottom.

***Option 3 (Preferred Method)***

The final method is to import wait from react-testing-library, set your test as asynchronous and then `await wait()` whenever you have async code:

```
...
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup, wait } from "@testing-library/react";

...

it("changes state/content from email to code when submit clicked", async () => {
  const { getByTestId, debug } = render(<RENDER THE COMPONENT>);

  const submitButton = getByTestId("fpwSubmitButton");
  expect(submitButton).toBeInTheDocument();

  const emailInput = getByTestId("fpwEmailInput");

  fireEvent.change(emailInput, {
    target: { value: "testemail@testemail.com" }
  });

  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  await wait()

  const codeInput = getByTestId("CodeInput");
  expect(codeInput).toBeInTheDocument();

  debug();
});
```

All of these solutions work because they wait for the next event loop before executing the test code. `Wait()` is basically a wrapper around `flushPromises()` with the added benefit of including act(), which will help to silence test warnings.

Answer (score 0):

**try something like this**

```
forgotPassword: jest.fn( async email => {
    return await new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        if ( email ) {
            resolve( email );
        } else {
            reject( "Error" );
        }
    } );
} );
```

**If it doesn't work let me know.**

Comment: thanks very much for your response! I have tried what you suggested and unfortunately it hasn't worked... I have edited my question and padded out the component definition a bit so it is a little more clear, not sure that this will help